# Duplicate a Communication Site in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, duplicate, communication-site

Is it just me or is this not possible?

I have tried making my communication site into a template (not possible) and making a copy to a subsite (not possible).

Do you have any suggestions? - scripting or using 3rd party service? or is such a simple action just impossible?

Please come up with ideas.

Answer (score 4):

To save the site as a template, we can directly access to /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx.

For example: https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx

We still can save the communication site as the site template using this way.
I have tested it, it works.

For more information, you can refer to [this blog](https://hangconsult.com/2017/06/29/change-sharepoint-online-root-site-collection-to-use-the-new-communication-site-template/).

If access denied when accessing /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx, [connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161372.aspx) and set [denyaddandcustomizepages](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161394.aspx) of this site to false for allowing it.

Comment: Thanks Joanna, but are you sure this is possible to do to a communication site? As far as i can see, communication sites are not yet supported by the SPO template

Comment: We still can save the communication site as the site template by accessing /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx. I have tested it, it works. I have edited my original answer and post the details steps there

Comment: FYI, I just tested with a Modern Communication Site and worked just fine. X-fingers no issues later